# Sentinel-2 Swath identifiers

Tags: coordinate-system, remote-sensing, sentinel-2

Is there a standard way of referring to a repeat-swath of a Sentinel-2 MSI acquisition?
For example the swath shown in the figure below is repeated every 5 days.
[image: Single Swath of Sentinel-2 Satellite]
(Here it is further split in to component UTM Tile/units.)

For Landsat-8 there is an implicit repeat-swath identifier in the WRS-2 Orbital path number. I can't see a mention of such an identifier  in the [Sentinel-2 Handbook](https://sentinel.esa.int/documents/247904/685211/Sentinel-2_User_Handbook)

Answer (score 1):

I got the following advice from the [s2btx forum](https://forum.step.esa.int/t/sentinel-2-swath-identifiers/10553/3?u=gbrelstaff):

> Sentinel-2 has Relative Orbits ... that provide the 10-day repeat
>   cycle of the mission acquisition.... IN each Tile, the Relative Orbit
>   can be deduced from the component **RXXX** in the filename, where XXX is a
>   number between 001 and 143.

Furthermore, it turns out that XXX is in time rather than longitude order - that  is why it doesn't increment in a simple manner as you go westward round the globe.

A KML(Keyhole Markup Language) file displaying the relative orbits is available [here.](https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/missions/sentinel-2/satellite-description/orbit)